# how to write into cronjob from a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, ksh

I would like to automate cronjob (meaning schedule a job to be done from a shell script). So i have script that does this

```
#!/bin/ksh
timestamp=$(date +%H%M%S)
if [ "$timestamp" -eq 230000 ]; then
 write to cronjob to execute the same script @ 11:00 PM
fi
```

so the output should be like below, is this possible?

```
00 23 2 10 2 /home/test/run_cron.sh
```

Comment: You know that your script will only do something when run at exactly 23:00:00, right? And (only) then it will add a cronjob to run every day at 23:00:00. Next day, it will add another such job. Same for 3rd and 4th and every following day. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: That's correct. Made the right edits. i need it run for that night and not any other night.

Comment: Seems you are looking for an `at` job, not a `cron` job. `at` jobs are run just once at some time in the future. Might that better suit your needs?

Comment: How do you manage to run the script at _exactly_ 23:00:00? Else the `if` won't trigger...

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

You can write to `crontab` via `stdin`:

```
echo  '0 23 * * * /home/test/run_cron.sh' | crontab -
```

The downside is that this clears all the previous `crontab` entries.

If you must keep already present entries (and not start from scratch), something like this should work:

```
echo "$(crontab -l ; echo  '0 23 * * * /home/test/run_cron.sh')" | crontab -
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you only want to be added to `crontab` ONCE. Therefore one must remove the script from the `crontab` first:

```
#!/bin/ksh
myname="$0"  

(crontab -l | grep -E -v "$myname";echo " 0 23 \* \* \* $myname") |\
    crontab -
```

Comment: Crontab does not have the script when run for the first time correct, why should we remove it?

Comment: @ady6831983 Because the next day the crontab will already contain the job and you don't want to add it twice.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and your updated question I read you want to run your script not *every day* at 11pm but only once the next day at 11pm. While this is possible with `cron` I suggest using an [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/at.1.html) job instead.

When adding a cronjob for this, we would need to calculate the next day's date (to setup something like `0 23 2 10 * …` for Oct 2) and then again remove that cronjob the next day. As said: *possible* but cumbersome. Hence, an `at` job. You may need to install the `at` command via `sudo apt install at`.

The syntax of `at` is a bit surprising: the command to be run is not given as a parameter but read from *stdin*, so we need to pipe it into `at`. Some examples:

```
echo "ls -l > out1.txt" | at now + 2 minutes
echo "ls -l > out2.txt" | at 23:00
echo "ls -l > out3.txt" | at tomorrow
```

In your case:

```
echo "./test-script.sh" | at 23:00
```

This will run `test-script.sh` the next time it is 11pm.