# Editing root crontab with startup script on fresh installed ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, cron

I'm building a script for my ubuntu server. the script creates a lot of files which works just fine, but now i come to a part where i need to add a line to the crontab of the root user.

If I do it manually i would type `sudo crontab -e -u root` and edit it crontab, but i want to automate it for this server. In my script i use `cat <<'EOF' > /sample/of/a/location.php` to create and fill files.

how do i do this for the crontab of the root user? I've read that the location is /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ but i am not supposed to edit them directly.

Can somebody help me out here?

Greetings,
Lennart

Comment: On Stack Overflow: [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1080045/504066

Comment: Ok, so after some testing the only thing i got working (i have zero linux knowledge) is `(crontab -l -u root ; echo "#0 20 * * * php /user/bin/scripts/mailqueue.php") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -` This does seem to work but it doesnt append. it just replaces it completely with this entry. also if i edit the crontab it says **"File: /tmp/crontab.ZwVMiq/crontab"**. tis /tmp/ part gives me the feeling its not the right file?

Comment: Don't worry, that's fine: when you do `crontab -e` then the _real_ crontab is copied to a temporary file (like your `/tmp/crontab.ZwVMiq/crontab`) and the editor is invoked on that file. When you leave the editor, that temporary file is copied back over to the _real_ crontab file (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$user`). So that's normal and expected behaviour.